# mysql check when a row was last updated

Tags: mysql, events, if-statement, sql-update

I am writing a MySQL Database and I wish to do the title within the MySQL database itself via Events if possible. I am updating the database via a Windows Service written in VB.net and have no desire to do the below via a separate 'server control' type program.

Basically, I have written the below in to the Database, but it doesn't quite do what I want:

```
Create Event MachineOffline
On 
    SCHEDULE Every 2 Minute
Do 
    UPDATE maindb.monitortable SET Online='1';
```

I would like it to say something like the below:

```
Create Event MachineOffline
On 
    SCHEDULE Every 2 Minute
Do 
    IF **RowX updated < 2 minutes ago** then
    UPDATE Database.Table SET Online='0' where RowX(ID);
```

I have no idea how to achieve this hence my question to everyone. I have no desire to create

Comment: you need another field in your database - `last_updated`, then you just check and set that as necessary.

Comment: Ok - @pala_ could MySQL do a compare on that field and the current_timestamp to run the if statement? Thanks otherwise!

Comment: yep thats exactly what it can do.

Comment: @pala_ - OK, I may be a tad lazy, but what would that code look like? Or, can you point in the way of documentation to show this type of code?

Comment: okay i put that into an answer for you - does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your Database.Table an extra column, lets say, `last_updated timestamp`, you can then update it like so:

```
update Database.Table 
  set online=0, last_updated = now()
  where last_updated <= now() - interval 2 minute
    and online=1
```

Comment: that's such a great solution, thanks so much! I'll be using this in my project, for sure. Didn't know MySQL did the 'interval' function, I'll have to look into this more.

Comment: its shorthand notation, there's a whole series of functions for dealing with date and time differences. [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)